# Create new file in x86_64 assembly in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to use the `open` syscall in Linux, from the manual page it takes 3 arguments, the `pathname`, `flags`, and the file `mode`. I tried to implement it with assembly x86_64 (Linux), but it doesn't create the file. By the way, where does the return value of this syscall is stored? The return value of `open()` is the file descriptor of the file, which then I want to write into.

```
section .text
    global _start

section .data
    pathname db "/home/user/Desktop/myfile.txt"

_start:
    mov rax, 2 ; syscall open
    mov rbx, pathname ; absolute path
    mov rcx, "O_CREAT" ; flag (create)
    mov rdx, "w" ; write (create file if not exists)
    syscall
    
    mov rax, 60
    mov rbx, 0
    syscall
```

The duplicate seems not to work for me, it doesn't create the file. And my path is valid.

```
section .text
    global _start

section .data
    pathname db "/home/user/Desktop/myfile.txt"

_start:
    mov rax, 2
    mov rdi, pathname
    mov rsi, 0x441   ; O_CREAT| O _WRONLY | O_APPEND
    syscall
    
    mov r8, rax      ; save the file handle
    
    mov rax, 60 ; exit syscall
    mov rbx, 0 ; 0 successful
    syscall
```

Comment: `O_CREAT` is not a string. It's a macro that expands to a number.

Comment: And `mode` is also a number containing the permission modes of the file, not a string like `w`

Comment: It seems like you didn't actually read the documentation of `open()`, it shows the datatypes.

Comment: The result is in `eax`.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I didn't know that. By the way, the duplicate's answer uses `rax`, `rdi` and `rsi` as the registers for the syscall, I am using `rax`, `rbx` and `rcx`, is this valid?

Comment: I don't really know assembly programming on Linux. But I have no reason to believe that the duplicate is wrong.

Comment: @DuduFaruk: ebx, ecx, edx, etc. are the arg-passing registers for the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI.  So yeah, it looks like you got that wrong, too.  Perhaps you were trying to port a 32-bit tutorial to 64-bit mode, even though you don't know assembly?  Related: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)  (But you're not even doing that, you're still using `syscall` so you just have the args in the wrong registers)

Comment: @Barmar The duplicate does not work for me, see the edit. You should ask if this helped me before closing my question

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm using and compiling with 64bit, I don't see anything wrong here. AFAIK `rax`.. are used with 64bit asm

Comment: @DuduFaruk: I found that duplicate for you, not Barmar.  Your code is in the `.data` section.  Put it in `.text`, data in .data.  Also, don't forget to 0-terminate your path string.  Also, don't forget to pass a `mode` arg for the permissions of the newly-created file, like 0q666.

Comment: @DuduFaruk: Yes, RAX for the call number, with args in RDI, RSI, RDX, R10, R8, R9, as per the x86-64 System V ABI docs.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) RAX is correct, that's why I didn't mention it being part of what you did wrong, only RBX and RCX.  Use `strace ./my_prog` to see what args you're passing.

Comment: @PeterCordes omfg, the link you provided just answers all of my questions, thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes One more question, do I need to close the file after using the `open()` syscall, or asm take care of that? I can guess that I do need to close, but just to be sure

Comment: The `_exit` syscall which you invoke at the end will close all open files (see `man _exit`).  It's good practice to explicitly close all files that you open, unless there's some good reason why it's inappropriate or impractical, but it isn't strictly necessary.  (But this has nothing to do with assembly language as a language; the language never does anything except what you tell it.  It's a question of what the OS does.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh right, I knew that. Thanks and sorry for obvious question